# Update parameters for parallel calculations using Python

Tags: python, numpy, dask, dask-distributed, ray

I have some Python code that performs the operations listed below. The `calc_result()` function generates results based on the input parameters. At each step, those input parameters are updated to calculate a new set of results. This process is repeated until the final step. Example code of this process is given below.

1. Define initial parameters
2. Calculate results based on initial parameters
3. Update parameters based on the results
4. Calculate results based on the updated parameters
5. Repeat 3 and 4 until final step

### Working example

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import time

def calc_params(res: list) -> list:
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return [r * 1.1 for r in res]

def calc_result(param: float):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return param + 1

def main():
    tic = time.perf_counter()

    nsteps = 10
    nmodels = 4
    init_params = [5, 4.5, 8, 2]

    steps = list(range(nsteps))

    params = np.zeros((nsteps, nmodels))
    params[0] = init_params

    results = np.zeros((nsteps, nmodels))

    for step in steps:

        step_results = []

        for p in params[step]:
            out = calc_result(p)
            step_results.append(out)

        results[step] = step_results

        if step < nsteps - 1:
            params[step + 1] = calc_params(step_results)

    toc = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'\nElapsed time {toc - tic:.2f} s\n')
    print(f'Parameters\n{params}\n')
    print(f'Results\n{results}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
    main()
```

This example prints the following output:

```
Elapsed time 22.75 s

Parameters
[[ 5.    4.5   8.    2.  ]
 [ 6.6   6.05  9.9   3.3 ]
 [ 8.36  7.76 11.99  4.73]
 [10.3   9.63 14.29  6.3 ]
 [12.43 11.69 16.82  8.03]
 [14.77 13.96 19.6   9.94]
 [17.34 16.46 22.66 12.03]
 [20.18 19.21 26.03 14.33]
 [23.3  22.23 29.73 16.87]
 [26.73 25.55 33.8  19.65]]

Results
[[ 6.    5.5   9.    3.  ]
 [ 7.6   7.05 10.9   4.3 ]
 [ 9.36  8.76 12.99  5.73]
 [11.3  10.63 15.29  7.3 ]
 [13.43 12.69 17.82  9.03]
 [15.77 14.96 20.6  10.94]
 [18.34 17.46 23.66 13.03]
 [21.18 20.21 27.03 15.33]
 [24.3  23.23 30.73 17.87]
 [27.73 26.55 34.8  20.65]]
```

### Dask example

I tried to parallelize the code using Dask as demonstrated below.

```py
import numpy as np
import random
import time
from dask.distributed import Client, get_client, secede, rejoin

def calc_params(res: list) -> list:
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return [r * 1.1 for r in res]

def calc_result(param: float):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return param + 1

def solve_step(step: int, nsteps: int, params: np.ndarray) -> list:
    client = get_client()

    futures = client.map(calc_result, params[step], priority=10)
    secede()

    step_results = client.gather(futures)
    rejoin()

    if step < nsteps - 1:
        params[step + 1] = calc_params(step_results)

    return step_results

def main():
    tic = time.perf_counter()

    nsteps = 10
    nmodels = 4
    init_params = [5, 4.5, 8, 2]

    params = np.zeros((nsteps, nmodels))
    params[0] = init_params

    steps = list(range(nsteps))

    futures = client.map(solve_step, steps, pure=False, nsteps=nsteps, params=params)
    results = client.gather(futures)
    results = np.array(results)

    toc = time.perf_counter()

    print(f'\nElapsed time {toc - tic:.2f} s\n')
    print(f'Parameters\n{params}\n')
    print(f'Results\n{results}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

    client = Client(n_workers=8)
    print('\n' + client.dashboard_link)

    main()

    client.close()
```

The output from the Dask example:

```
Elapsed time 1.85 s

Parameters
[[5.  4.5 8.  2. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  0.  0. ]]

Results
[[6.  5.5 9.  3. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]
 [1.  1.  1.  1. ]]
```

The Dask example does not update the parameter values therefore the results are not properly calculated. Is there a way to update the parameters array while calculating the results in parallel? I tried to follow the approach in the Dask example [Handle Evolving Workflows](https://examples.dask.org/applications/evolving-workflows.html) but it doesn't seem to work for this problem. Dask also has [Actors](http://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/actors.html) but according to the docs it's an experimental feature and the Dask dashboard does not display information when using Actors. Another package for scaling Python is [Ray](https://www.ray.io) but I have no experience with it.

Comment: Focus on parallelizing and optimizing `calc_params` and `calc_resuls`. You can't overcome iterative nature of your problem.

Comment: @dankal444 Can you submit an answer that demonstrates your suggestion?

Comment: There is nothing to demonstrate since your `calc_params` and `calc_results` functions are just dummies.

Comment: Now that I look at it, you could parallelize on `models` axis I think

Comment: @dankal444 When you say `models` are you referring to the `calc_results` function?

Comment: I think both `calc_results` and `calc_params`. If I understand this correctly, each model have independent results and independent param.

Answer (score 1):

given your problem description, it seems like the process of iterating is important to the algorithm. so I don't know how you're supposed to be able to parallelize this. Dask can't magically know what the result of a later step is. "evolving workflows" in that example is referring to workflows that trigger more jobs - that's different from your case, where each workflow stage depends on the previous one.

Consider a very simplistic example of your workflow:

```py
result = 0
for i in range(10):
    result += 1
```

You could refactor this to be:

```py
def inc(val):
    return val + 1

result = 0
for i in range(10):
    result = inc(val)
```

but what you can't do is

```py
 # results in a list of 10 futures, each of which results in the number 2
result = client.map(inc, val=result)
```

Comment: Can Dask Actors be used for this type of problem? Maybe the parameters can be stored and updated with the actor. https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/futures.html#actors

Comment: the problem isn't which type of dask object to use. the problem is that your algorithm is fundamentally structured to run in series. You might be able to partition the problem a different way (can subsets of the problem be solved iteratively and then combined together?) but you can't use *any* parallel processing to solve an iterative problem like this.

Comment: The parameters and results arrays could be divided into chunks where each chunk is operated on. But I'm not sure if that would help with the overall speed.